# Can an AST in statutory periodic phase notice to quit be submitted to a landlord casually by WhatsApp?

Tags: england-and-wales, tenancy-rules

Suppose Alice lets a room to Bob, under a written contract that is incorrectly labelled as a lodger's agreement, however, Alice does not live in the property, thus automatically rendering Bob an assured shorthold tenant.

The initial fixed term was a month, after which it rolled into a statutory periodic AST.

2 weeks ago, Bob sent Alice a rather informal notice to quit by WhatsApp. He is now having difficulty finding alternative accommodation, and has asked Alice for permission to stay longer, which she has denied. Is Bob bound by his original informally served NTQ, or was it legally ineffective?

Comment: Can you clarify if you're talking about s.21 and not s.8, please

Comment: Sorry if this wasn't clear, but I was actually talking about neither, as s21 and s8 are both notices served by a LL to a tenant. In this case I am referring to notice to quit by a tenant presently intending to vacate in a month's time.

Comment: Bob is the tenant, Alice the landlord.

Comment: Okay, the reference to NTQ confused me but I've got it now!

Comment: Glad to hear. And yeah, Valid methods of Service of s21 & s8s has been thoroughly covered in a previous question. In short eg s21 must be on a form 6a and cannot be as informal as a candidly worded message. Whether the proper form can be served electronically or not depends on whether tenant has consented in writing to receive notices electronically.

Comment: This appears very similar to [one of your earlier questions](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/80806/what-happens-after-a-deed-of-surrender-or-notice-to-quit-is-signed-delivered-and). Is the crux of this about whether an NTQ delivered by WhatsApp is valid?

Comment: Yes, the rest of the background info is--perhaps-- superfluous. The crux is as you said about validity of WhatsApp delivered NTQ. I imagine that it is valid because the technical procedural requirements on landlords stem from the tenant's right to quiet enjoyment of their home which implicates the human rights act and the landlord has no such human rights-implicating interest in the affair but rather one of a business nature. But I'm trying to confirm in case I'm wrong. Finally I can't recall any especially similar past questions.

Comment: Oops, you actually linked to the past question. No, this is different, in that yes exactly as you say, the crux is whether service by WhatsApp is valid.

Comment: OP, could you please double check your spelling within the first paragraph? too short an edit at my rep. sp/am/an ?

Comment: What is sp/? Is it sed syntax? I understand s/ for substitute but what is sp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been unable to find a definitive answer on this. However, the consensus where this has been debated elsewhere on the web seems to be:

- If the tenancy agreement states how notices should be served (e.g. in writing or via e-mail, to specified addresses), then you should use those methods.
- In theory, if you send a notice via WhatsApp, and the landlord replies in a manner which clearly and unambiguously indicates that they have accepted your notice as valid, then it is valid.

Comment: Makes good sense.