# What is the landlords recourse for a tenant that doesn't leave after an expired notice to quit?

Tags: england-and-wales, landlord, eviction

For most more common scenarios, there are clearer prescribed judicial procedures with defined fees etc. A solicitor advised me today that an expired notice to quit may be dealt with as a section 8 notice for breaching the terms of tenancy by failing to leave after one has agreed to and then upon the  expiration of the s8 apply to the court for an order of possession. How else could this be dealt with?

Comment: This seems very similar to [a previous question of yours](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/80806/what-happens-after-a-deed-of-surrender-or-notice-to-quit-is-signed-delivered-and). In any case: if you serve a section 8 notice, then that strongly implies that a tenancy is still in place. So your solicitor seems to be suggesting that you effectively ignore the NTQ.

Comment: Similar, yet slightly different. I don't think they're suggesting that you ignore the NTQ as indeed, the uncomplied with NTQ is forming the very basis for ground of the s8.